# Django - How to access the verbose_name of a Model in its Admin Module?

Tags: django, django-admin

How to access the `verbose_name` of a Model in its Admin Module? We can access the same if we have an instance of that model like below.

```
instance._meta.verbose_name.title()
```

Comment: @Daniel Yes. Something like 'ModelName.Meta.verbose_name'

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`Model._meta.verbose_name.title()`

and

`Model._meta.verbose_name_plural.title()`

return singular and plural Model's verbose names accordingly. There's also `Model._meta.verbose_name_raw` property, it seems to return unicode string for me, while `verbose_name.title()` returns a normal string, but I'm not sure what's the real difference between this and `verbose_name.title()`.

Comment: The method described above seems to work in Django 1.2 and python 2.6.  Do you get a runtime error or a message from PyDev or some other static analysis tool? It looks like Django uses at least some "magic" under the hood while creating _meta attribute, so static analysis may produce false errors, while the code is valid and can be successfully executed.

Comment: Eventhough PyDev shows the error, It works perfectly. Created a bug item for PyDev too. Thanks.

Comment: @SivasubramaniamArunachalam where is this bug item? What did the dev say?

Answer (score 6):

`Model._meta.verbose_name.title()` returns verbose name with First Character Uppercase while `Model._meta.verbose_name_raw` property returns the verbose name you wrote in the model class.

Comment: .title() is nothing more as str method. So we can access Model._meta.verbose_name (without .title()). The name is translated into django.utils.translation.get_language() (of course: if you have defined it with gettext). Model._meta.verbose_name_raw will return the original text in your sources without any translation.