# How to call model verbose_name in class based view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a `UpdateView` class based view:

```
class CompanyUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'companies/company_update.html'
    fields = '__all__'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        title = str(self.object)
        messages.info(self.request, 'Company ' + title + ' updated')
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

My model has a `Meta` `verbose_name` defined:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Company'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Companies'
```

Is there a way to display the model's `verbose_name` in the `form_valid` function so I am not writing

```
messages.info(self.request, 'Company ' + title + ' updated' )
```

but instead something like:

```
messages.info(self.request, self.request.META['verbose_name'] + title + ' updated' )
```

?

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070417/django-how-to-access-the-verbose-name-of-a-model-in-its-admin-module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the `Options` object of the class by calling `._meta` and obtain the `.verbose_name` of that model:

```
def form_valid(form):
    messages.info(self.request, form.instance._meta.verbose_name + ' updated.')
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

so in this specific case, you can implement this with:

```
class CompanyUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'companies/company_update.html'
    fields = '__all__'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        messages.info(self.request, '{} {} updated.'.format(
            self.object._meta.verbose_name,
            str(self.object)
        ))
        return super().form_valid(form)
```